# Bootstrap 3: How to code my banner?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone have any advice on how to place a small image at the bottom of my banner? See this attachment (circled in red) to get an idea of what I am talking about. Can I do this using CSS3 or am I better off just placing an image there? It would be great if that image could adjust with the length of the heading text (e.g. "Our Capabilities") for each page. Entire HTML can be viewed at: 
[HTML link](http://www.ogmda.com/test/help.html) and green image is at: [Green Image](http://www.ogmda.com/test/bar.png)

[image: Goal of project]

My HTML code:

```
<section class="page-top">
    <div class="container">
                <h2><em><strong>OUR CAPABILITIES</strong></em></h2>
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS code:

```
section.page-top {
background-color: #161616;
border-top: 5px solid #35557c;
border-bottom: 5px solid #97c05a;
margin-bottom: 35px;
min-height: 50px;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
```

}

and

```
section.page-top h2 {
color: white;
font-weight: 700;
background-color: #97c05a;
display: inline-block;
padding: 7px 9px;
height: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px 1px 15px 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px 1px 15px 1px;
border-radius: 15px 1px 15px 1px;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:after` with `position:absolute` and `background-size` to make the image resize with the content:

```
section.page-top h2 {
    position:relative; /*Add this to your h2*/
}

section.page-top h2:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background: url(http://www.ogmda.com/test/bar.png) no-repeat right center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```